# SNS topic not firing when attached to EventBridge rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

I've set up an SNS topic that notifies through an email. It's working when I ask to test it through the AWS console. It sends a test email.

I've set up an EventBridge rule that should trigger when security group related actions are executed. I've set the target for that rule to be the SNS topic i described above. But when I make changes to my security groups (through the AWS console or through API calls), no emails are sent.

Can someone look into my configuration and tell me what else I can look into?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the actual logs in CloudTrial to verify what events are triggered when you change your SGs?

Comment: Yes, the event source and event names match. Everything is in CloudTrail event history. What is really strange is that even when I change it to pass all events from EC2 to the SNS topic, it still doesn't send any messages.

Comment: Did you create CloudTrial trial, or just using event history?

Comment: Oh wait, do I have to enable it? I'm just checking history.

Comment: Yes, you have to have a trial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have trail enabled for EB to detect API events. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-ct-api-tutorial.html):

> To record events with a detail-type value of AWS API Call via CloudTrail, a **CloudTrail trail with logging enabled is required**.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I started with the following solution to my problem, which does not involve CloudTrail: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-security-group-changes-ec2/. That's why I never thought it was needed. But this means I will not select EC2 as the service name, but CloudTrail instead. So the question becomes what does selecting EC2 as the service do? Why do I have that option?

Comment: @AlexandreMartini No problem. Not sure what do you mean with EC2? `AWS API Call via CloudTrail` will not work without the CloudTrail trail.

Comment: I just created a trail, which created a bucket in S3 with logging enabled. Then I changed my rule to events coming from CloudTrail and defined all operations by hand (security group related). Everything looks OK, but the events that I see in event history still do not trigger my rule in EventBridge.

Comment: @AlexandreMartini I'm not sure what you did. I would suggest making new question with new details of your setup.

Comment: @AlexandreMartini Also please provide details of your [sns permissions for EB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-use-resource-based.html#eb-sns-permissions). Maybe they are incorrectly set.

Comment: Thanks for all the help... I discovered AWS Config, which makes it all a breeze to configure. It's working even better than I thought it would! Thank you again!